# docker build failed No repomd file

Tags: linux, docker, centos

Trying to build a docker image

```
docker build INGInious-Docker
```

The Dockerfile is

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 1.1.0

#inherit from the default container, which have all the needed script to launch tasks
FROM    ingi/inginious-c-cpp
LABEL org.inginious.grading.name="intro_v2"

# Update yum, install pip, update pip
RUN     yum -y update
RUN     yum -y install gcc-c++
RUN     yum -y install python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

# Install git
RUN     yum -y install git

# Install Scenario
RUN     pip install --upgrade  git+https://github.com/shlomihod/scenario.git
```

I have to say that this `Dockerfile` was successful in building 2 months ago. All I did was changing the name 
from `LABEL org.inginious.grading.name="intro" to`LABEL org.inginious.grading.name="intro_v2"`

getting this Output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  22.02kB
Step 1/8 : FROM ingi/inginious-c-cpp
 ---> 9f81381415b0
Step 2/8 : LABEL org.inginious.grading.name "intro_v2"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33750672d068
Step 3/8 : RUN yum -y update
 ---> Running in bb81fcdbb49a
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=<repoid>

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

File /var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/epel/metalink.xml does not exist
Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=x86_64 error was
No repomd file
The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y update' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: see `Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink`  this seems to be the source of the problem, is it valid?

Comment: @user2915097 see my answer.

Comment: ok. sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, very oddly, in the name `intro_v2`
I've changed it to `intro2` without the `_` and it worked.